# How to run a nx script and nodemon script in one-line shell command?

Tags: angular, shell, nodemon, npm-scripts, nomachine-nx

My project is Angular. I have added a script line for running `nx` and `nodemon` commands inside of the package.json. The first command runs but the second one does not. If I stop the process and then the second command starts to run. My code is like that:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "translate": "nx run my-project:serve --port=1202 & nodemon apps/my-project/src/assets/i18n/translate/index.js"
}
...
```

I could give an extra information. My laptop OS is Windows. This script works in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`concurrently` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both commands simultaneously.

```json
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "translate": "concurrently \"nx run my-project:serve --port=1202\" \"nodemon apps/my-project/src/assets/i18n/translate/index.js\""
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I solve the issue without any additional package like you mentioned above? The strange thing is why the script works on macOS but does not work on Windows.